# Final Fantasy VII - Train of Corel

Tags: final-fantasy-7

How do I stop the Corel Train in Corel (Playstation version)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**To Stop the Train (and get the Huge Materia and Ultima Materia)**

You only need to input 3 button combinations. The proper combinations, in order, are:

Up + Triangle, Down + X, Down + X.

**To Get onto the Second Train**

If you are having trouble speeding up the first train in order to catch the second, you simply have to alternate pressing Up and Triangle. So, press Up, Triangle, Up, Triangle, Up, Triangle, etc.

If you want more complete details on the possible outcomes on the train, go [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197341-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/45703) and search for this text "{32} The Huge Materia: Corel and Fort Condor"

Answer (score 2):

There is a 'proper' way to do this but oddly enough there's another (easier) way.

It's been a while since I've played but you choose the option to speed the train up. On the third time of speeding up it cuts to the CGI scene and stops.

Sorry I can't tell you exactly what buttons but as I remember it there is a prompt telling you how to stop the train. Deliberately don't follow those instruction so that each time the train gets faster.

Edit: I found a [clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtgxF-0HZmo#t=7m50s) which shows the process

Comment: Thanks! I've watched the clip after my train was already stopped, but maybe someone will find it very useful...although you can't see the key sequence used in the video.

Answer (score 1):

I have played FF7 many years ago, but I don't remember that I have big problem with Corel Train.

Looking through different forums and walk-troughs some people suggested to not follow the indications of buttons to quickly but instead suggest to take time and do them slowly.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to take my time trying to stop it! Finally I succeded!

Answer (score 0):

Succeded! As Dolbz suggests there's a way to stop that train that doesn't require to follow the instructions (also because those aren't very clear...).

I made it with down+cross (two times) and up+triangle (several times): the train seems to get faster and faster each time, then Cid screams "SHII---!" and then it stops just in front of Corel!

Comment: nice job! please comment @Dolbz answer instead of reply with your answer; and remember to mark the answer of @Dolbz if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: I've marked as accepted answer the one from Ian because he gave the actual combination; I gave upvote (and thanks) to marco.ragogna and Dolbz because their answers are helpful...but since I succeded using my own method I think that my answer must stay where it is. Ian's IS the correct answer, though. Do you agree?